# SFTP certificates not being recognised

Tags: ssh, sftp

We currently access a third party's axway sftp server manually via a web ui 
and would like to set up a passwordless login to allow automatic downloads.

I have made sure the authorized_keys file is located in the correct path, that it has the correct permissions and in the right format.  There is now three keys in the file; one for rsa, dsa and ecdsa. None seem to work.

We only have sftp access; no ssh.

As the third party is a multinational bluechip company with slow turn around time for technical queries I would like to be able to make an accurate request in the first instance.

Here is the output of -vvv:

```
kevin@ubuntu:~/.ssh$ sftp -vvv <SERVER NAME CHANGED TO PROTECT THE INNOCENT>
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Applying options for <SERVER NAME CHANGED TO PROTECT THE INNOCENT>
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <SERVER NAME CHANGED TO PROTECT THE INNOCENT> [nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/kevin/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/kevin/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/kevin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/kevin/.ssh/id_dsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/kevin/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: identity file /home/kevin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/kevin/.ssh/id_ecdsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/kevin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 3
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.ECDSA-256
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.ECDSA-256
debug1: identity file /home/kevin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SSHD
debug1: no match: SSHD
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [<SERVER NAME CHANGED TO PROTECT THE INNOCENT>]:2222
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[<SERVER NAME CHANGED TO PROTECT THE INNOCENT>]:2222" from file "/home/kevin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/kevin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha256,hmac-sha256@ssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha256,hmac-sha256@ssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 129/256
debug2: bits set: 513/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn
debug3: put_host_port: [nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn]:2222
debug3: put_host_port: [<SERVER NAME CHANGED TO PROTECT THE INNOCENT>]:2222
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[<SERVER NAME CHANGED TO PROTECT THE INNOCENT>]:2222" from file "/home/kevin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/kevin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn]:2222" from file "/home/kevin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/kevin/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '[<SERVER NAME CHANGED TO PROTECT THE INNOCENT>]:2222' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/kevin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 524/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/kevin/.ssh/id_dsa (0x7f221aa9f240)
debug2: key: /home/kevin/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f221aa9f200)
debug2: key: /home/kevin/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x7f221aaa09d0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/kevin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/kevin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering ECDSA public key: /home/kevin/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
Password Authentication
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
```

The authorized_key file contains:

```
ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAACBA ... SQx9wCtDG8R3== kevin@ubuntu
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXN ... pbrwdxE= kevin@ubuntu
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1 ... E5siYjCX3/b8qNjuGzPQoBRX kevin@ubuntu
```

(I ended up with three keys as the debug output showed that sftp was attempting all three types)

This shows the access rights of the files on the remote server:

```
sftp> ls -la
drwxr-x---   1 1000025  1000025      4096 Dec 08 21:50 .
drwxr-x---   1 1000025  1000025      4096 Dec 08 21:50 ..
drw-------   1 1000025  1000025      4096 Dec 08 02:03 .ssh
[snip]
sftp> cd .ssh
sftp> ls -la
drw-------   1 1000025  1000025      4096 Dec 08 02:03 .
drw-------   1 1000025  1000025      4096 Dec 08 02:03 ..
-r--------   1 1000025  1000025      1170 Dec 08 02:03 authorized_keys
```

My suspicions are that:

- they have disabled passwordless access in which case is the above the expected output?
- I'm not using the right username in the authorized_keys file
- Some thing else altogether

Really appreciate some help in this matter as it has already chewed up an annoying amount of time.

Comment: Gone with using an Expect script, seems the third party have disabled all things useful and forced us to hack this script with plain-text password.

Answer (score 0):

The authorized_key file is not relevant, because it contains the public keys that allow logging onto your pc. You should instead offer the remote system the private key of the public/private pair that was generates to allow you to connect to the remote system.

In other words, you should issue the command:

```
   ssh me@remote_server -p 2222 -i .ssh/private_key_for_the_remote_server
```

Comment: Sorry, no cigar:  

    kevin@ubuntu:~/.ssh$ sftp -i id_dsa  foo.bar.com  
    Password Authentication  
    Password:   
    kevin@ubuntu:~/.ssh$ sftp -i id_rsa  foo.bar.com  
    Password Authentication  
    Password:  
    kevin@ubuntu:~/.ssh$ sftp -i id_ecdsa  foo.bar.com  
    Password Authentication  
    Password:  
    kevin@ubuntu:~/.ssh$

Comment: Erm, formatting fail...

Comment: @KevinPluck Those do not appear to be valid private keys. Does the file that contain them begin with -----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY----- or some such thing? If not, they are not private keys.

Comment: They look good to me:

    kevin@ubuntu:~/.ssh$ cat id_rsa id_dsa id_ecdsa
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIIEowIBAAKCAQEA6V0ZMu630vapgEpMLOziHB79X6mJwXcHthMr6E8B61BRkq+x
    [snip]
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    -----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIIBugIBAAKBgQCJ6H75joDH31bPKdAT+KlCQl8YGD+0+jY8I97JzwLeHl/pXuq/
    [snip]
    WsGb/DeIcOGw1B2eq00=
    -----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    -----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
    MHcCAQEEIGxbtwj1JAQ0c6dqKidWI3TjAP37gqRDU9AUn7T8kmZDoAoGCCqGSM49
    [snip]
    -----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----